# wp_query is not returning post details, if logged out

Tags: wordpress

I am very beginner to wordpress. I am trying to this past one week.
I have stored email template as post. I am trying to fetch that post while clicking forgot password.

If I use to call same method after login it is working.But for me it should work in login page.

I am not able to figure out what is causing the issue ? Please help out of this.

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'custom_email',
   'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key'     => 'email_notification',
     'value'   => 'reset-password'
    ),
    array(
     'key'     => 'email_notification_disabled',
     'value'   => 'true',
     'compare' => '!=',
    ),
   ),
  );

  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $posts = $wp_query->query( $args );
  return $posts;

Comment: I don't know, why is  this behavior, but in the first meta query you need to add the `compare` key, and why do you query twice? Use `$posts = WP_Query($args);`